# SonarQube - no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped

Tags: jenkins-plugins, sonarqube, jacoco

I'm running SonarQube in a jenkins job (using Post-build Actions).
I'm getting the following problem with JaCoCo -

```
[INFO] [16:57:43.157] Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
[INFO] [16:57:43.157] Project coverage is set to 0% as no JaCoCo execution data has been dumped: /var/lib/jenkins/.../target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] [16:57:43.426] Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 269 ms
```

As a result, I'm getting 0% code coverage for my project.
Couldn't find why jacoco.exec is not being created.

I don't have "JaCoCo" configured to run by maven (in my pom.xml).
I know that in the past the jacoco.exec was created anyway (probably by Sonar itself).

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to configure JaCoCo in my pom.xml for it to work?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/1fca5c965196c0f30ef8fa4c79ace36b40ec3753/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/ut/ut-maven-jacoco-runTests ?

Comment: How should I use it with my jenkins job? 
Where should I use "-Pcoverage-per-test" in the job configuration?

Answer (score 4):

From the web [Java Ecosystem](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Java+Ecosystem):

> It is no longer possible to let SonarQube drive the execution of the
>   unit tests. You now have to generate the JUnit and code coverage
>   (JaCoCo or Cobertura or Clover) reports prior to the SonarQube
>   analysis and then feed SonarQube with those reports.

So you need to include Jacoco in the pom.xml:

```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
       <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.7.0.201403182114</version>
   <configuration>
       <destFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
       <dataFile>${basedir}/target/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
   </configuration>
       <executions>
           ...
       </executions>
   </plugin>
```

And give this data file to SonarQube:

```
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco-unit.exec
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog](http://intellectualcramps.wordpress.com/2012/03/22/jacoco-tycho-and-coverage-reports/) you can enable the creation of `jacoco.exec` files by adding the following plugin section to your `pom.xml` (it worked for me):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1.201405082137</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```